# Describing conformal maps in terms of a complex functional equation.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-writing, functional-equations

Conformal maps have the interesting property that they map circles and points to points and circle.

I wonder if the only holomorphic functions with this property are conformal maps. But I realized I don’t know any way to write “mapping lines and circles to lines and circles” as a functional equation which can then be solved  or approximated for a collection of functions (which would in principle be the conformal maps).

Comment: No, conformal maps do not have that property; not every conformal map is a linear-fractional transformation. (Also you stated the property wrong: linear-fractional transformations take _lines and circles_ to _lines and circles_.)

Comment: Ah that’s a good clarification. Is it known that linear fractional transforms are the only such maps to do this?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I doubt it. Hmm, the answer below says yes...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the functions that take lines and circles to lines and circles are precisely the Möbius transformations

$$f(z) = \dfrac{az+b}{cz+d},\quad \text{with} \ \ ad-bc\neq0.$$

I began writing an outline of the proof, but then I found this pdf, which is reasonably self-contained and goes into far more detail than I was willing to type here:

http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~sb/CA_sectionIVnotes.pdf